# What gulp.src() → gulp.dest() returns and why it works in gulp#4.x?

Tags: node.js, gulp

According gulp#4.x documentation, gulp task must return the one of the following:

- stream
- promise
- callback function
- child process
- RxJS Observable

However, the following task working without error:

```
gulp.task('test', () => {
    return gulp.src('source/**/*.*')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

But what of the above ones it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, gulp.src:

> Returns a stream of Vinyl files that can be piped to plugins.

And gulp.dest:

> ...will write files [and]... Re-emits all data passed to it so you can pipe to multiple folders